# Questions on "simple-connectedness-like" property

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I wanted to know if there's any notion which is very similar to the simple connectedness, but defined "purely" in terms of points and sets.

Here's my attempt to do it. Let $X$ be a topological space. If there exists open connected subsets $U$, $V$ in $X$ such that $U \cup V = X$ but $U \cap V$ is disconnected, let's say that $X$ is non-simply onnected. (It doesn't agree with the usual definition. But for simplicity, let's call it just simple connectedness) If $X$ is not non-simply connected, let's say that $X$ is simply connected.

I want to know if the new notion of simple connectedness satisfies the followings:
(but it was difficult for me)

1. If $X$ is simply connected and $r:X \to A$ is a retraction, $A$ is also simply connected.
2. Let $U, V$ be open subsets of $X$ such that $U \cup V = X$. If $U, V$ are simply connected and $U \cap V$ is connected, then $X$ is simply connected.
3. If $X$ and $Y$ are simply connected, $X\times Y$ is also simply conncected.

Can anyone prove/disprove these statements?

Comment: One problem with your definition: some disconnected sets will not be "non-simply connected" (because, for example, there do not exist open connected subsets $U, V \subset X$ eith $U \cup V = X$) and therefore it will be defined as "simply connected."  I doubt that's what you want.

Comment: If you want, you may put connectedness in the definition. But I think there will be no big difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your property is called "open-unicoherence"; see [this article](http://texedores.matem.unam.mx/publicaciones/phocadownloadpap/Anales-vol29/29-artculo2.pdf), "A survey on unicoherence and related properties", by A. García-Máynez and Alejandro Illanes.